# How do I route by path in DC/OS?

Tags: haproxy, marathon, dcos

Let's say I have a single domain `fooapi.com` and two versions of the API: v1 and v2. How do I configure HAProxy in the `marathon.json` file so that both API versions can live behind the same domain but with a different path? Eg. `fooapi.com/v1/` and `fooapi.com/v2/`.

The following configuration doesn't work (latest DCOS):

```
"labels": {
"HAPROXY_0_VHOST": "fooapi.com",
"HAPROXY_DEPLOYMENT_GROUP": "api-grp",
"HAPROXY_GROUP": "external",
"HAPROXY_0_PATH": "/v1"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading through the Marathon-lb docs, I've solved it by adding the `HAPROXY_0_HTTP_BACKEND_PROXYPASS_PATH` config parameter:

```
"labels": {
"HAPROXY_0_VHOST": "fooapi.com",
"HAPROXY_DEPLOYMENT_GROUP": "api-grp",
"HAPROXY_GROUP": "external",
"HAPROXY_0_HTTP_BACKEND_PROXYPASS_PATH": "/v1",
"HAPROXY_0_PATH": "/v1"
}
```